# Unable to create match in gamecenter

Tags: ios6, game-center, xcode4.6

I have a turn based game by using game center.

It was works fine but, now 
When I try to give request it shows " unable to create game ".

Why this usually happening.

[image]

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @RyanCaskey: I had faced the problem 2 year back. I forgot it.